# Defining functions in a loop

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, functions

I have a symbolic solution to a linear system with respect to some variables a[i,j] which depend on a parameter t.

```
sol=Solve[...,Table[a[i,j],{i,0,n},{j,0,n}]]
```

I would like to make functions from the solutions. Something like

```
a[i,j][t_]:=a[i,j]/.sol[[1]]
```

When I do it by hand, everything is fine. But when I try to get it in any loop, like

```
Do[{a[i, j][t] := a[i, j] /. sol[[1]]}, {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}]
```

it doesn't work.

For example, when I'm trying to look at a[0,1][t] it gives me

```
a[i,j]
```

How can one define a family of functions in a loop?

Comment: Use `Table` rather than `Do`.

Comment: @verbeia Are you sure this is a simple issue? It seems to me that the OP is not looking for a table of functions, he wants a series of functions *defined*. From a quick look at the text I'd say the problem lies in the HoldFirst attribute of the SetDelayed function.

Comment: Well, that's how I read it, but if the post shoud be reopened, I won't object. I just can't help feeling there is a dupe, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: I meant to say `HoldAll` attribute. If you change `:=` to `=` it works. This enables evaluation of the RHS. Additionally, in the definition you  probably should change `t` to `t_`.

Comment: This might work: `(#1[t_] := Evaluate[#2]) & @@@ First[sol]`. Hard to be sure without a working example to test it on..